# How Haskell's "composing lenses using function composition" with that weird order of arguments could be implemented?

Tags: haskell, records, higher-order-functions, function-composition, lenses

I've been reading [A wreq tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/tutorial.html):

> A lens provides a way to focus on a portion of a Haskell value. For
>   example, the `Response` type has a `responseStatus` lens, which
>   focuses on the status information returned by the server.
>
> ```
> ghci> r ^. responseStatus
> Status {statusCode = 200, statusMessage = "OK"}
> ```
>
> The `^.` operator takes a value as its first argument, a lens as its
>   second, and returns the portion of the value focused on by the lens.
>
> We compose lenses using function composition, which allows us to
>   easily focus on part of a deeply nested structure.
>
> ```
> ghci> r ^. responseStatus . statusCode
> 200
> ```

I can't come up with a way how function composition done with this order of arguments could treat the nesting structure in that order.

Look: `r ^. responseStatus . statusCode` could be either `r ^. (responseStatus . statusCode)` or `(r ^. responseStatus) . statusCode`.

In the first one says we construct a function which **first** treats `statusCode` (gets it from the record `Status`? -- as I can deduce from the shown value `Status {statusCode = 200, statusMessage = "OK"}`), and then passes it to `responseStatus` which must treat the response status. So, it's the other way round: in reality, the status code is a part of the response status.

The second reading also doesn't make sense to me because it treats the status code first, too.

Comment: `statusCode` must be a lens, not the record field selector. I guess they must have hid the field selector and exported a lens of the same name; pretty confusing if you ask me. (Or wrote a custom Show instance.)

Comment: @ReidBarton That must be a part of the puzzle. Since I know very little about lenses, my question is also a question about the underlying idea: how normal function composition can be used for accessing the structure in reverse order? (This reminds me continuation-passing style a bit.)

Comment: That's essentially correct. Lenses are kind of like CPS computations of a kind so they, as a side effect, flip function composition.

Answer (score 15):

The right reading of `r ^. responseStatus . statusCode` is `r ^. (responseStatus . statusCode)`. This is only natural, since function composition returns a function when applied to two arguments, thus `(r ^. responseStatus) . statusCode` must return a function, as opposed to any value that could be printed out.

This still leaves open the question why lenses compose in the "wrong" order. Since the implementation of lenses is a bit magical, let's look at a simpler example.

`first` is a function that maps over the first element of a pair:

```
first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first f (a, b) = (f a, b)
```

What does `map . first` do? `first` takes a function acting on the first element, and returns a function acting on a pair, which is more apparent if we parenthesize the type this way:

```
first :: (a -> b) -> ((a, c) -> (b, c))
```

Also, recall the type of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

`map` takes a function acting on an element and returns a function acting on a list. Now, `f . g` works by first applying `g` and then feeding the result to `f`. So `map . first` takes a function acting on some element type, converts it to a function acting on pairs, then converts it to a function acting on lists of pairs.

```
(map . first) :: (a -> b) -> [(a, c)] -> [(b, c)]
```

`first` and `map` both turn functions acting on a part of a structure to functions acting on the whole structure. In `map . first`, what is the whole structure for `first` becomes the focus for `map`.

```
(map . first) (+10) [(0, 2), (3, 4)] == [(10, 2), (13, 4)]
```

Now take a look at the type of lenses:

```
type Lens = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)
```

Try to ignore the `Functor` bits for now. If we squint slightly, this resembles the types for `map` and `first`. And it happens so that lenses also convert functions acting on parts of structures into function acting on whole structures. In the signature above `s` denotes the whole structure and `a` denotes a part of it. Since our input function can change the type of `a` to `b` (as indicated by `a -> f b`), we also need the `t` parameter, which roughly means "the type of `s` after we changed `a` to `b` inside it".

`statusCode` is a lens that converts a function acting on an `Int` to a function acting on a `Status`:

```
statusCode :: Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> (Status -> f Status)
```

`responseStatus` converts a function acting on a `Status` to a function acting on a `Response`:

```
responseStatus :: Functor f => (Status -> f Status) -> (Response -> f Response)
```

The type of `responseStatus . statusCode` follows the same pattern as we've seen with `map . first`:

```
responseStatus . statusCode :: Functor f => (Int -> f Int) -> (Response -> f Response)
```

---

It remains to be seen how exactly `^.` works. It's intimately tied to the core mechanic and magic of lenses; I will not reiterate it here, since there are quite a few writings about it. For an introduction I recommend looking at [this one](http://blog.jakubarnold.cz/2014/07/14/lens-tutorial-introduction-part-1.html) and [this one](http://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-1), and you could also watch [this excellent video.](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/4251-lenses-compositional-data-access-and-manipulation)